# How to separate returned results with a character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list of checkboxes and I'm getting a string of the label of each checked box, each separated by comma's.
The label is a sibling of the input box. I can get the text, but how can I add commas?

Here is a snippit of my HTML:

```
...
...
<div class="ui-checkbox">
    <input id="abc" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="abc">
        <span>
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Two Words</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
<div class="ui-checkbox">
    <input id="abc" value="1" type="checkbox">
    <label for="abc">
        <span>
            <span class="ui-btn-text">Joe</span>
        </span>
    </label>
</div>
...
...
```

And my one liner of jQuery:

```
string = $('input:checked').siblings($("ui-btn-text")).text();
```

This gives the following result: ***"Foo Bar Meth Two Words Joe"***.

But I want: ***"Foo, Bar, Meth, Two Words, Joe"***.

What can I add here to get the comma?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
$('input:checked').next().find(".ui-btn-text").map(function(){
      return $.trim(this.innerHTML);
}).get().join(', '); //If you do not want a space after comma then just .join()
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/fHLLQ/)**

Answer (score 1):

```
string = $('input:checked').next().map(function () {
    return $.trim($(this).text())
}).get().join();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/vx5YS/)